.htaccess deny file access does work for all types but not for php files
I'm on an apache2 installation and want to deny access to a specific php file with a .htaccess file
<Files test.php>
  Require all denied
</Files>

Which does not work. However, denying access to a different file type does work as expected
<Files test.html>
  Require all denied
</Files>

I've tried with various file types, all work as expected, except for php files. What do I miss here? I'm using php-fpm.
Solution
Got it working now, the solution from @life888888 down below guided me to the right direction. The main issue was, that there's an entry in my site config, which got added by the webpanel I'm using
ProxyPassMatch ^(.*\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/$1

Commenting out this line and adding
<FilesMatch \.php$>
  SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
</FilesMatch>

instead solved it. Now calls to php scripts are still using PFP-FPM, but htaccess and other directives are working now as expected!
Thanks again so much for all the help and comments, especially from @life888888

try put the code block  in httpd.conf or apache2.conf (<Directory "/path/to/your/directory"> and </Directory>

Doesn't work either. The weird thing is that no matter what file type I want to block in my .htaccess file, it just works except for php files.

I assume you have more than just these lines in your configuration. Since there is some additional factor involved here it makes sense that you show all of that implementation. I could for example imagine that you have a rewriting rule in place that matches requests to /test which might, in combination with MultiViews, lead to such behavior.

The content in my post above is the only thing I'm havin in my htaccess. Might iz have something to do because I'm using php-fpm?

The preferred location for rewriting rules actually is the central http server's host configuration. Check there for additional directives. Distributed configuration files (typically called ".htaccess") are only a last option if no other is usable.

Apache 2 + php-fpm
My Test Environment
Ubuntu 20.04
Install Apache 2 And Php
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y 
sudo apt install apache2 -y
sudo apt install php php-fpm -y
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-fcgid -y

Enable Necessary Apache Modules
sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif

Configure Apache to Use PHP-FPM
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Within the <VirtualHost *:80> block, add the following lines:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    
    # PHP-FPM Configuration
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>

    <Files "info.php">
        Require all denied
    </Files>
    ...
</VirtualHost>

Note: Ensure to replace php7.4-fpm.sock with the actual socket path for your PHP version. You can check this by looking into the /run/php/ directory.
Note: No .htaccess , I put it in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
Restart Apache and PHP-FPM Services
sudo systemctl restart apache2
sudo systemctl restart php7.4-fpm

Create Test php
sudo nano /var/www/html/info.php

Add the following content:
<?php
phpinfo();
?>

sudo nano /var/www/html/info2.php

Add the following content:
<?php
phpinfo();
?>

Test 1
use Firefox or curl open http://localhost/info2.php
Test 2
use Firefox or curl open http://localhost/info.php
will get error:
403 Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.
Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

IMPORTANT:
if test all ok , delete /var/www/html/info.php and /var/www/html/info2.php
Summary
I am test all steps OK in my ubuntu 20.4
My test environment always starts with re-copying a cleanly initialized Ubuntu VM.

This guides me to the right direction I think. I just noticed that (because I'm using a webpanel?) there's this line within my site config ProxyPassMatch ^(.*\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/$1. Your code works perfectly fine, but I have to comment out that line. Question is, is this a problem?

@andy  I can't find ProxyPassMatch ^(.*\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/$1 in my config file. My Apache 2 is Apache 2.4.41 (Ubuntu). PHP and fpm is version 7.4. You can check your environment.

Yes this line was added to the config by my webpanel and seems to be the problem. After commenting out this one and add your <FilesMatch> directive in a modified way (because I'm not using sockets), htaccess works fine. My directive looks like that: SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000". Question is if there's something not working when commenting out the above mentioned line.

I've edited my initial post and added the solution. Since you guided me there, your answer is the one solved my problem, thanks so much!
